# How to integrate my custom C#/ASP.NET webpages on to already hosted DotNetNuke version 7.0.1 website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I already have a custom C#/ASP.NET website which consist of one master page with several child pages. And the child pages are interrelated.
In the website i also have several custom utility classes and from child pages i am calling these classes.
And the website is also connected to SQL database and from code it is calling several custom class libraries for data processing.

Now i need to integrate this custom website onto a DotNetNuke website.
I have already hosted DotNetNuke website of version 7.0.1.

How can integrate my website on to the hosted DotNetNuke website ?

I found 2 solutions,
first one is to use an DNN Iframe module, but i can't use the option.
 second option is by converting individual webpages as usercontrols and adding as DNN modules, but in my case the website has a master page, interrelated child pages and utlility classes. So it will huge task for converting every pages as usercontrols in order to create DNN modules.

Can anyone suggest a better method for integrating my webpages onto the hosted DNN website.

Answer (score 0):

What we did was keeping 2 websites. Via same styling of masterpage and the DNN skin, it looks like one website for the enduser. Use a link from DNN to the Asp.NET website. You can use a custom roleprovider to use the same authorizations

```
public class DNNRoleProvider : System.Web.Security.RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DNNDB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT r.RoleName FROM dbo.UserRoles ur INNER JOIN dbo.Roles r on ur.RoleID = r.RoleID INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON u.UserID = ur.UserID WHERE u.Username = @username";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", username));
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            using (reader)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    roles.Add(reader["RoleName"].ToString());
                }
            }

            return roles.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        bool ret = false;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DNNDB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT count(0) FROM dbo.UserRoles ur INNER JOIN dbo.Roles r on ur.RoleID = r.RoleID INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON u.UserID = ur.UserID WHERE u.Username = @username and r.RoleName = @rolename";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", username));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("rolename", roleName));
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            using (reader)
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    ret = reader[0].ToString() == "0" ? false : true;
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    //rest of interface implementation

}
```

Comment: problem in my case is that i cant't keep 2 websites, i need to integrate my custom website on to DNN website, so that can inherit some DNN features like giving roles and permissions, like restricting some users from accessing some particular pages in my website

Comment: We created a custom RoleProvider which used the DNN tables